# How can I heat up my apartment more efficiently?

Tags: heating, energy-efficiency

I live in a studio apartment that I rent from my parents, in France. Each winter, it gets very cold. The region is very sunny, but the specific area around my building is significantly colder (due to being in a small valley, a water stream nearby, tall trees, etc). The building is very old (1800s) and made out of stone. My studio has two floors: the second floor (main area) and a bedroom upstairs, under the roof.

I did not heat my apartment from spring to November, but this past few days, it has been very cold and I need to act. The temperature in the studio dropped from 20ish degrees celsius to 11.5 in a matter of days. The problem is that I track my power consumption using an app provided by the electricity company, and as soon as I turned on the heaters, my daily cost went from 1.90€ to 7.50€. I unfortunately cannot afford to pay this daily for the whole winter.

Here is how the apartment is heated.

**Second floor** (main floor, kitchen, office, bathroom):

- There is a new generation ["ceramic inertia heater"](https://www.mariniere-energie.fr/tradition-plus.html) underneath the kitchen window (facing south).
- There are two old school electric radiators under the windows facing North
- There is a heating towel rack in the bathroom, that I never really use
- The kitchen window is well located but really tall trees prevent a lot of sunlight from entering the room. Each day, I have to turn on the lights, except between 11 AM to 2 PM approximately.

**Third floor** (bedroom, under the roof)

- There is a ceiling window (Velux) on the roof, facing South
- There is an old oil radiator that I can move around and that I sometimes turn on at night.

Additional details:

Last week, I did not heat my apartment and it went down to 11.5 degrees Celsius when I came back from work at 6 PM.
The apartment below mine is not inhabitated, neither is the one across the hall from my entrance door.
I cannot install a wood furnace, a petrol heater or the like. All windows, Velux included, are double-paned glass.

**My current heating strategy**:
This is what I am currently doing. I turn on the kitchen window radiator to 13.5 degrees. I put the ones on the two other windows oon anti-freeze mode with the dial on 2 or 3. I do not use the bathroom's radiator because the heat from my shower is enough for comfort. At night, I sometimes turn on the oil heater in my bedroom, to the minimum setting. I wear a sweater, slippers, and put a drape over myself when I sit at the computer for a long time.

I'm being as frugal as I can be, but I am very cold and expected to pay 200+ euros at the end of the month for electricity only. I am willing to keep living like this, but if you have any advice or solution, it is more than welcome.

Here is a plan of my apartment (proportions are wrong):

[image: Diagram of my apartment.]

Comment: Mini split  heat pumps are about the best bang for money when running.  Much better than the electric heaters you have now.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks for the quick answer. I forgot to add, unfortunately the building is classified as a historic building and I am not allowed to add anything outside :(

Comment: About the only other advice is to increase insulation and to seal all drafts around windows/doors to help keep the heat in.  Adding insulation the walls is a big job usually if the walls are already finish.

Comment: Dang, I was hoping there would be another way! There's actually a project to renovate the roof, and unfortunately it might mean that my ceiling window has to go (again, because classified building).

Comment: You say nothing about insulation or the construction of the roof.  Those are crucial details; insulating the roof is likely to be the most cost-effective way to improve things.

Comment: All your heat sources (new or old) are "toaster" heat. That is electric resistance. 100% efficient, but only 100% efficient, where heat pumps can be 300-500% efficient (more typically 300) on the same fuel. Heat pumps do have a high inital cost, but the much lower running cost soon pays off. Of course, insulation pays off even faster, if you have uninsulated stone walls...

Comment: I'd investigate if there's a way in the historic rules to add something outside but some meters away from the historic building, which would thus not alter the building exterior. Otherwise, get historic and start covering the walls inside with heavy tapestries for the winter.

Comment: You could use electric resistance heated garments like electric socks or electric heating pad for the feet or an electric blanket. Some of these would be corded but others could be battery powered, e.g., an electric vest. If the floor is cold, then an insulating rug or pad under your feet while sitting will improve comfort. Wear gloves with open finger tips.

Comment: Aren't the stairwells labelled wrong in the diagram?

Comment: What is on the "first" floor? A separate apartment? A garage? Do you wear an insulating cap on your head in rooms at 13.5 C? Is 11.5 C just the temp when you arrive home and you raise the air temp of the space to 13.5 C (56 F) when you are home?

Comment: Would it be allowed to cut down one or a few trees to allow direct sunlight on the structure? I love trees and have always lived in excessively hot and sunny locales where the shade from trees was desirable, but your situation is the opposite.

Comment: How much do you pay per kWh? If your unit rates are similar to mine, you're using a similar amount of heat as I do for quite a big (but well insulated) house, suggesting your insulation is really in need of improvement. I don't keep mine very warm, but a significant few degrees warmer than yours

Comment: If the trees are deciduous, they'll soon be shading the building much less

Comment: Sitting on an XPS or EPS insulating foam panel, your body's heat feels amazingly warm. Sitting on such a chunk of insulating foam might make you considerably more comfortable at your computer. Even double pane windows are pretty useless for keeping heat inside, so you could use that same insulation material over windows at least 50% of the time.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments and apologies for the late replies. @ChrisH, I paid 41€ in October for 182 kWh, so that would be 0.225€/kWh (+16€ subscription cost).

Comment: @ChrisH, the trees outsides are massive sycamore trees. Deciduous, but they have very thick branches and they still cast a lot of shadow without leaves.

Comment: @JimStewart, the first floor is an apartment that the landlord decided not to rent out. So it's basically an empty apartment, unheated. 11.5°C was the temperature of my apartment unheated (basically outside temp, now it has dropped). I used to let the heater set to 13.5°C, whether I'm home or not. Now I set it higher, to 15ish degrees.

Comment: OK, so you used about 6kWh each day.  Not all of this will have gone on heating, but most will Electricity used by the PC, lights etc. will end up as heat, so it's only really if you heat water electrically then it goes down the drain taking heat with it.  Most of my heating is gas, but my gas and electricity combined comes to about 8.5kWh/day for a big house at 16°C when I'm there alone, to 18°C when my daughter is there.  You're losing a lot of heat.

Comment: Even wrapped up warm, indoor temperatures consistently that low are cold enough to have health effects.  You need to find where insulation will be most useful.  What's the inside of the roof/lost ceiling like (pictures)?

Comment: If this is a young person who is dressed for warmth, I would think that 15 C would be OK.

Comment: How is the water heated? Is there hot water at the kitchen sink or just in the shower? Is the cooking stove gas or electric? Do you do much cooking?

Comment: Does this apartment have its own water heater or is there a common water heater for several units? Is the water heater a storage tank or is it a tankless? Gas fired or electric?

Comment: Is there a cooktop and separate oven or a stove with all in one unit? If the surface burners are electric, are they resistance or induction? Do you ever turn on the oven or the surface burners for extra space heating?

Comment: @JimStewart Just a gas cooktop and an eleectric oven. I bareley turn on the oven except for when I have people over.

Comment: To address other comments, I now set the heaters to around 14.5 degrees. It's not that cold when you move around. The water heater is electric and a bit too big for a single person (300L I think). There's hot water in the sink, the washing machine, the dishwasher, etc. I usually cook once a day but these past few weeks I've been out a lot.

Comment: What gas is used by the cooktop? Do you have piped in gas or do you use gas from a tank or bottle? Wow a 300 L (80 galUS) hot water tank!? In the US this would serve a large family! This is probably an electric resistance water heater so this would be a significant electric power load. To save on electricity you may have the temperture set point on this tank relatively low, possibly far lower than international guideline of 60 C (140 F). The purpose of keeping the water in a tank at 60 C is to prevent growth of certain harmful bacteria, specifically Legionella. Where is the tank located?

Comment: A 1-bedroom apartment should not need more than a 150 L hot water tank. In this day and age the hot water tank should be an electric heat pump type which uses about 1/3 of the electric energy of an electric resistance heater. However, heat pump WHs cost more, require more service, make some noise in operation, AND cool their surroundings! Where is this tank located? What temp do you have it set to? Is the hot water scalding? Moderately hot? Lukewarm? For showering how much cold water do you have to meter in?

Comment: @JimStewart Yeah, I gotta look into changing it. The thing is, when I'm not renting the studio, my parents rent it out to tourists and they may need a lot of hot water. It's a 2-bedroom apartment actually, and with 1 double bed, 2 simple beds and the convertible couch, you can fit 6 people easily. The tank is in the bathroom (cylinder on my plot). The water is quite hot, but not incredibly so. I'll try to tune it down a little bit.

Comment: I did not advise you to turn the set temp down on the WH. If you turn it down too low, you could allow Legionella bactera to grow in the storage tank and infect yourself or the renters. Don't change anything without checking with the owner of the apartment.

Comment: Better still don't take it upon yourself to change the setpoint of the water heater. You will be responsible if this goes wrong.

Comment: Okay, indeed good advice. I checked yesterday annd I think I can't even change the water heater without the appropriate tools to turn the dial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add insulation:
start adding heavy curtains to the windows on the north side of the building,
then insulate the ceiling of the top floor (under the roof), if you have enough height, consider a suspended ceiling otherweise just add insulation panels under the shingles from outside.

Consider double-glazing, at least the windows facing north.

Use heat-pump to heat instead of resistive heaters, it's 3 five more efficient than electric (your 8€/day will go to around 3€/day just for that). A 3-split system may be enough (also if you already have the AC, check if it can also do heat, as said is much more efficient than resistive).

Consider moving the PC in the bedroom, so you'll avoid to heat a room with no much use (or, better, move the bed at the second floor so you avoid heating the loft that is much more wasteful having 5 sides exposed instead of 4)

Comment: If you abandon the loft for the winter, you'll need to close it off somehow as warm air will convect up there. There may already be a door of course.  I stayed for a few days somewhere like that (usually only rented out in summer but it was winter), and we had to get creative with clips and weights to cover the top of the stairwell with a blanket.  That made a huge difference to keeping the lower floor warm

Comment: Hi, good ideas, thank you. All my windows are already double-glazed and I cannot install a heat pump (building limitations), but I did add heaevy curtains to close off the north-facing part of the house. I tried moving my desk upstairs, and closing off the lower bedroom. My plan is for th Velux to heat up the house during the day, and close it with a thick built-in curtain at night.